# Eclipse generates method with fully qualified argument types

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes, when I use content assist in Eclipse to override a method of superclass (or auto-generate method stub in any other way), the generated method signature has all types fully-qualified, has "{}" right after signature (without wrapping) and has ";" after the method. For example:

```
    public void doSomething(com.company.xyz.First first, java.lang.String string) {};
```

Why does it do this? I don't have any other classes imported that may clash by name with the auto-generated ones. And I can't see why ";" may be needed after method in any case.

Comment: Does it really put `java.util.String` or is it `java.lang.String`?

Comment: `java.lang.String`, of course. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist. Check 'Add import instead of qualified name'. This will disable generation of qualified names.

Line wrapping is something to do with your code formatter. Windows->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Edit->New Lines Tab. Check 'in empty method body'

Comment: I had both of those options checked, but methods were still generated in that strange way.

Comment: Thats weird, I tried enable-disable options I mentioned. I was able to replicate the behavior you mentioned and fix it.

Comment: This behavior happens not always, but under some conditions I cannot figure out. Mostly it happens when I'm overriding a method.